# Node.js: fs.existsSync doesn't work on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, fs

I have a Heroku app using Node.js and Express, and I want to determine whether or not a certain file exists. However, it seems like the file is never found. I have the following path:

```js
app.get('/sims/:sim_name', (req, res) => {
    var simName = req.params.sim_name; // get the name of the requested sim from the URL
    // if it exists, render it
    if (fs.existsSync(`pages/sims/${simName}.ejs`)) 
        res.render(`pages/sims/${simName}`);
    // otherwise, show an error message
    else
        res.send("Sorry, the page you requested does not exist.");
});
```

The directory structure of my project looks like this:

```
.
├── Procfile
├── README.md
├── app.json
├── index.js
├── node_modules
│   ├── so many node_modues...
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── public
│   ├── images
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── lang-logo.png
│   ├── node.svg
│   ├── scripts
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── stylesheets
│   │   ├── ...
│   └── test.html
├── test.js
└── views
    ├── pages
    │   ├── index.ejs
    │   ├── sims
    │   │   └── EField.ejs
    └── partials
        ├── header.ejs
        └── nav.ejs
```

I am doing something wrong here? Or is this a Heroku issue?

Comment: Heroku doesn't really do "persistent files", and worse: if this is a hobby dyno your content gets _reset_ when the dyno goes to sleep. It just restarts the original slug. So: if you need persistent storage, don't use files. Add a free database or file store, and use that instead. Having said that: log what you're doing. Log the file you're trying to access, then on herokuapp.com go to your dyno, upper right, "more..." fire up the console, and see what's going on with your files.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans the file I am trying to find is actually a permanent page of the website, not one created by the site itself (if you know what I mean), so really I don't see why it shouldn't be persistent.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I just tried using the console to find the page I am looking for and running `cd views/pages/sims && ls` shows EField.ejs, the file I am looking to render. so, it seems like it is where I think it is, yet I still can't access it. Howver, I tried a few variations of `fs.existsSync('pages/sims/${simName}.ejs')` and I am still getting nothing.

Comment: remember to make paths fully qualified paths. `pages/sims/...` _relative to what_? So you definitely want a `const filePath = path.join(__dirname, ....)` in there, and then log that to make sure it's _really_ the correct path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I needed to change `pages/sims/${simName}.ejs` to `views/pages/sims/${simName}.ejs`.

I had previously tried `/views/pages/sims/${simName}.ejs`, which didn't work because of how the file paths work in Heroku.

I also added braces, as per the suggestion of @UserToday (although this wasn't necessary).

Answer (score 1):

The undisciplined way you code is like asking for trouble! Start using curly brackets wherever needed!

Here's the corrected script...

```
if (fs.existsSync(`pages/sims/${simName}.ejs`)) 

   { res.render(`pages/sims/${simName}`);}

else
   { res.send("Sorry, the page you requested does not exist.");}
```